# How can I insert a string in an IO stream in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, io, stream

I'm trying to write a Ruby script that will tweak a SQL dump (taken from `pg_dump`) so it can set up a table cleanly.

So far it's been all good the way I've set it up; I've been able to `File.read` the file, insert a word, append some stuff to the end, and `File.write` the file again.

However, I'm now working with a dump that's nearly 7 GB, and it won't cope (`File.read` is raising `EINVAL` errors, and there's no trouble with the filename). So I want to use a single stream to find the right spot to insert that word, and then jump to the end and append the extra stuff.

But I can't *insert* that word. I want to change

```sql
DROP TABLE public.programmes;
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

to

```sql
DROP TABLE public.programmes CASCADE;
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

but using `file_stream.puts` (`#write` and `#<<` aren't any better), I end up overwriting part of the following line:

```sql
DROP TABLE public.programmes CASCADE;
ch_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

... and I'd rather not have to loop (read eight characters, seek back eight characters, write previous eight characters) all the way to the end of the file, 7 GB away.

(I might be okay with doing it back to the start of the file – that's only 460 B – but I'd still have to know how to insert some characters at the start.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to insert bytes without overwriting anything then you have to make a hole and put your bytes in that hole: i.e. you have to move all the bytes after `public.programmes;` to make room for `CASCADE;`, write `CASCADE;`, and then repeat for each other match. Or easier, don't try to edit the file in-place, add your `CASCADE` stuff while streaming the original to a modified copy and then delete the original. If you only have one edit then making a single hole shouldn't be too messy, if you have several edits then making a copy will be easier.

Comment: Oh, I must have taken that note out while drafting this – 7 GB is also a lot of data to have a redundant copy of, however briefly, so I'm not keen on doing that either. There is only one insertion, and then some appendments. Maybe I'll have to bite the bullet and cycle through the file :/

Comment: Does it have to be ruby? It seems like sed might be a better tool for this, given the file size & task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the place where `CASCADE` needed to go was so close to the start, I ended up writing eight characters to the file *first,* then appending the results of `pg_restore`. Then I could loop through the file stream from the start and drop the string into place...

```rb
# Could be any eight characters, but these are a valid SQL comment in case it fails
File.write(path, "-------\n")
system("pg_restore #{pgr_options} >> #{path}")

File.open(path, 'r+') do |stream|
  content = ''
  stream.pos = 8

  # The semicolon is needed to delimit the table name
  content << stream.getc until content =~ /(DROP TABLE public.[a-z_]*);/
  stream.rewind
  stream << content[0..-2] << ' CASCADE;'
```

... before jumping to the end and appending stuff.

```rb
  stream.seek 0, :END
  stream.puts "ALTER TABLE ONLY blah blah blah..."
end
```

Comment: Why not something like `pg_restore ... | sed ... > some_file`? And 7GB really isn't that much these days, my wheezing old iMac has 1TB drive and even my phone has a spare 7GB.

Comment: 7GB isn't much for a one-off, but if this happens frequently then the free space gets filled up fast. And I use Ruby because (1) it's nicer than `sed` and (2) there are other parts to the script that it's better suited to.